# Select query using aggregate function & it need to optimized

Tags: sql, select, query-optimization

An `Employee` table contains millions of rows, I need to fetch count of those employees whose salary is greater than 50,000 and I need to fetch row employee name is 'ajay'.

```
select count(*) 
from employee 
where salary >= 50000
```

For this query - is there any other way to get the same result using any aggregate functions?

```
select * 
from employee 
where empname = 'Ajay'
```

This select query is working, but it is time consuming since each rows has to be searched - I need an optimized query.

Please provide any alternatives for these two scenarios.

Comment: `create index ix1 on employee (salary)` and `create index ix2 on employee (empname)` will do.